# google hangout microphone is not working with network error and firewall setting issue

Tags: google-chrome, video-streaming, google-plus, google-hangouts

From last 1 week i am facing strange issue in google hangout. as i join a meeting first a message pops up

Your microphone is not working or is hardware-muted!

then after few seconds i see message

Couldn't start the video call because of a network error.
Please check your firewall settings and try again.

with button to try again. and it keeps going on in this way.

I have checked firewall settings
I have tried with different networks
I have tried with different computers
I have tested microphone and speakers they are correct

I inspected ajax calls in firebug and i see this

NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://plus.google.com/u/0/talkgadget/_/ping?id=1

NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://plus.google.com/u/0/talkgadget/_/ping?id=2

POST https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_/channel/bind?...200F2A8A372&RID=67018&AID=84&zx=2a53yvv7e45w&t=1 Aborted

Comment: I am also having this same issue. But I guess this is not an appropriate platform to ask this type of question. Try somewhere else.

Comment: Could you resolve this issue "Your microphone is not working or is hardware-muted!"?

Answer (score 0):

At google Community somebody answered like this:

> I have found the culprit.  I use Spybot Search & Destroy's Anti-Beacon software to block telemetry data that Windows 10 constantly sends to Microsoft.  This is why trying multiple Windows 10 machines that I have configured did not alleviate the problem.  Somehow one of the IP block entries it adds to the Windows Firewall now conflicts with Google Hangouts.  I will report this to the software vendor.

Source: https://support.google.com/hangouts/forum/AAAAfpFnBZ8mdNNg8LNvNg/